# Two projects on local environment

Tags: php, session

I have to projects that I'm working on on my local environment. Both use PHP sessions.

Whenever I log into one website, the other one shows that I'm already logged in, but it doesn't allow me to access the admin panel, since the username and password isn't in that projects database.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You could use different browsers, or private navigation or change the session cookie name of one of your project.

Comment: @Joucks what is mean by session cookie name?

Answer (score 0):

use different session variables. For website one use `$_SESSION['web1_user']` and for website two `$_SESSION['web2_user']` something like that

other option use **different browser** or **private window** or **incognito window**

Answer (score 0):

Both my dev and production servers are like that... I have an `app_settings.inc.php` file for each web app where I store a few constants like `APP_CODENAME`, and all of my sessions use `$_SESSION[APP_CODENAME]` as the "top level" variable, so `$_SESSION[APP_CODENAME]['authUser']="bsmith@example.com"`, etc. and logging out of a particular app is done with a simple `unset($_SESSION[APP_CODENAME])`